# I am trying to record an application on the intranet using Jmeter, but i keep getting DNS failure message

Tags: jmeter, authorization, recording

I am trying to record my application under test which is on the intranet using the Jmeter recording controller. It manages to capture the URL but then starts showing DNS failure and response code 503.There seems to be some authorization issue. Any ideas on how I can provide authorization details (username/password) at the time of recording ?

Comment: HTTP 503 indicating that a server is temporarily unable to handle the request. If it was authentication normally would be 401. You might have a DNS issue in which case try using IP instead of host name and see if that works, or firewall configuration maybe rejecting your request.

Answer (score 0):

1. For application authorization you can try adding [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager), it should be able to deal with at least [Basic HTTP Authentication](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter)
2. For proxy authorization (if your machine is using proxy for intranet/internet access) you can [specify username and password via `-u` and `-a` command-line arguments correspondingly](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) like

   ```
   jmeter -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password -N localhost
   ```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 503 status code indicates that a server is temporarily unable to handle the request.

So it would be a temporary failure of one of the intermediate components between JMeter and the server:

- DNS Server
- Proxy
- Firewall
- Load Balancer
- Web server (Apache HTTP, Nginx, NodeJS...)
- Application Server (J2EE, PHP, ASP servers)

An authentication error related to proxy would trigger a 4XX response code.

Checks the logs of each of the intermediate components , if you don't reproduce issue when using browser then have a look at:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server